# Is there a mercurial plugin to provide github style calendar contributions?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, d3.js

The github contributions calendar is really nice. Is there a mercurial plugin which produces similar d3.js calendars for Hg repositories?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The github calendar is not a feature of git (nor a mercurial missing feature), its a graphical display of repository changes made by github.

You can use a plugin to use the mercurial commands in a git repository, host it in github and have the calendar. Take a look at  http://hg-git.github.io/.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for something more like the activity extension (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ActivityExtension) rather than something that relies on moving a repo over to github. That plugin is very interesting though